# Twilio Video SDK - Network Quality Signaling error

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I have implemented the twilio-video SDK version 2.27.0, in a local environment the implementation works correctly but when testing with the application deployed on the server, I receive the following error when joining a room

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._networkQualityInputs.take(...).then(...).finally is not a function
    at t._sendNetworkQualityInputs (networkqualitysignaling.js:231:12)
    at new t (networkqualitysignaling.js:133:15)
    at new t (room.js:132:24)
    at t.<anonymous> (cancelableroomsignalingpromise.js:89:21)
    at Object.f (events.js:243:26)
    at s.emit (events.js:153:5)
    at t.r (twilioconnectiontransport.js:513:35)
    at s.emit (events.js:153:5)
    at t._handleMessage (twilioconnection.js:457:14)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (twilioconnection.js:338:27)
```

This is a snippet of the SDK implementation:

```
const room = await connect(twilioToken.data.token, {
            name: this.conversation.sid,
            tracks: localTracks,
            networkQuality: networkQualityConfiguration
          }).then(room => {
            console.log(`Successfully joined a Room: ${room}`);
            room.localParticipant.setNetworkQualityConfiguration({
              local: 2, 
              remote: 1 
            });
            return room;
          });
```

I am using version 14.18.1 of node, in a Vuejs application